# Java Library Documentation License

Tags: java, documentation, licensing

I'm working on an open-source compiler (GPLv2) that compiles to the JVM, and I wanted to be able to distribute Java's documentation together with the compiler and the java external classes definitions. How is Java's documentation license in this manner? If it's restrictive, can I use OpenJDK's documentation?

For what I've read at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/redist-137594.html, it seems that Oracle doesn't allow us to redistribute the API documentation. But what about OpenJDK?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems? Actually I need to ask back: Why do you think so? By just linking one website on that server?

Comment: It says on the linked site - The Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition, API Specification is not redistributable except internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am not a lawyer and this post should not be taken as legal advice.

Second, you are asking for legal advice.  You need legal counsel.  Get a lawyer.  A bunch of (semi)anonymous people on the internet should not be counseled for legal advice.  The law is often a parallel universe with complicated rules that do not always match our own, and words do not always mean what you think they mean.  You need an expert to help you through this.

Third, you should review the license provided by the source.  You've done that for Oracle, but you don't appear to have done that for OpenJDK.  Most of their licensing apears to be at http://openjdk.java.net/legal/ , though I didn't see anything specific about documentation.  JavaDoc is embedded in the source, and each source file is individually licensed (as per their [FAQ](http://openjdk.java.net/faq/))... there may be something along those lines, and there may not.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll look for the individual licenses of OpenJDK, it seems that most of them will have no problems with using the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Now, I don't know what happened to my bounty. I don't see it anymore to be able to award you with it. Not sure why?
[edit: just added a bounty again. will reward in 24 hours. thanks!]

Comment: @Waneck:  Glad I could help.  No worries with the bounty... I'm guessing it expired or something :)